# Error Code: 1064. MYSQL WORKBENCH

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, mysql

Olá estou tentando criar a seguinte tabela:

```
CREATE TABLE produtos(
id integer primary key auto_increment unique ,
nome varchar(255) unique,
descricao varchar(255),
preco varchar(10,2) ,
validade date  
);
```

E o seguinte erro sql é apontado:

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '2) , validade date   )' at line 5
```

Comment: Por que o `preco` está como `varchar(10, 2)`? Não deveria ser um tipo numérico?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss e por falar nisto, provavelmente `DECIMAL`, porque se usar FLOAT vai causar outro problema (não de sintaxe). Caro Marcos, troque `preco varchar(10,2)` por `preco decimal(10,2) `... Claro que tem que ver qual a média de preços que o sistema irá aceitar e ajustar conforme a necessidade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Preco varchar(10,2)`

O varchar aceita um parâmetro apenas.
Acredito que o que vc procura é o tipo `decimal(10,2)`

Comment: Thanks buddy, notei agora esse detalhe

Comment: Para facilitar para os próximos que tiverem o mesmo problema, se isso tiver solucionado, marque como resposta. Se não, adicione a resposta e a marque como correta.